# Set provider name manually in DbContext constructor

Tags: entity-framework, dbcontext, dataprovider

I need to store the connection string somewhere else other than web.config. Currency I am using a .json file to store it and a static class to read from it.

Here is my data context -

```
public partial class MyDatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDatabaseContext() : base()
    {            
        Database.Connection.ConnectionString = GlobalConfig.ConnectionString;
    }
}
```

This is GlobalConfig class

```
public static class GlobalConfig
{
    public static string ConnectionString
    {
        get
        {
            return "Server=MyServer; Database=MyDb; Integrated Security=SSPI;";
        }
    }
}
```

I need to assign provider name `System.Data.SqlClient` to the context. How can I do that here?

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to load ***DbConfiguration*** class at the DbContext Constructor

**Define a class that implement  DbConfiguration** (Oracle in this case)

```
     public class AppDbConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public AppDbConfiguration()
    {            
        // use code based configuration
        SetDefaultConnectionFactory(new OracleConnectionFactory());
        SetProviderServices("Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client",EFOracleProviderServices.Instance);
        SetProviderFactory("Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client", new OracleClientFactory());

    }
}
```

**Use it in your context**

```
    public AppDbContext(string connString) : base(connString)
    {
        DbConfiguration.SetConfiguration(new AppDbConfiguration());     

    }
```

Don't forget to install the currect Package for your provider (in this example its ODP.net from nuget package manager)